Tracking scroll events to hide/show a header bar
I have a script on a static html page that I would like to include or rewrite in a Blazor app. The script adds a class "scrolled" to the header top bar once the browser window has been scrolled past 100px. When the window is scrolled back up above 100px, the class "scrolled" is removed from the header element. The intention is to hide or show the header's top bar if the page has been scrolled up or down (see static demo below).
Can anyone explain how to inject the script into my Blazor app's index page or know of a similar working example using onscroll events in Blazor to achieve the same thing?
<< UPDATE >>
This post solved my issue:
Add/Remove Class Based on Scroll Position in Blazor
Here is the static demo (not using Blazor) showing how the topbar hides on scroll and then shows when scrolling back up:


(function() {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy on scroll event listener 
   */
  const onscroll = (el, listener) => {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }

  /**
   * Hide topbar on scroll
   */
  let selectTopbar = select('.topbar')
  let selectMenubar = select('.menubar')
  if (selectMenubar) {
    const menuScrolled = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        selectMenubar.classList.add('menu-scrolled')
        if (selectTopbar) {
          selectTopbar.classList.add('topbar-scrolled')
        }
      } else {
        selectMenubar.classList.remove('menu-scrolled')
        if (selectTopbar) {
          selectTopbar.classList.remove('topbar-scrolled')
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', menuScrolled)
    onscroll(document, menuScrolled)
  }

})()
/* Default Theme Overrides */
:root {
  --mdc-theme-primary: #00a0af !important;
  --mdc-theme-secondary: #f68e1e !important;
}
/* Main Nav Desktop */
body:has(.mdc-tab--active:not(:first-of-type)), body:has(.mdc-drawer-app-content .nav-btn-hide) {
  overflow-y: hidden; /* prevent double scroll bars */
}
.topbar {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #069;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menubar {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.mdc-tab-scroller {
  flex: 1;
}
.mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-drawer-container:has(.topbar-scrolled) {
  top: -40px;
}
.nav-drawer-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 100;
}
.nav-drawer-container:has(.mdc-tab--active:not(:first-of-type)) .nav-tabgroup-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.nav-drawer-container, .nav-drawer-container .nav-tabgroup-container, .nav-drawer-container .nav-tabgroup-container .mat-tab-group-content, #hero {
  width: 100%;
}
.mdc-tab-bar .mdc-tab, .mdc-drawer-app-content > div {
  height: 60px;
}
.nav-drawer-container a.flhc {
  content: "";
  background-image: none;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 167px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  margin-left: 0.75em;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-drawer-container .mdc-tab-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: start;
}
.nav-drawer-container .mdc-tab-bar .mdc-tab {
  max-width: max-content;
}
.nav-drawer-container .mdc-tab-bar, .mdc-drawer-app-content > div {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 102, 153, .25);
}
.nav-tabgroup-container span.mdc-tab__text-label {
  color: #006699;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.99em;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.01em #006699;
  z-index: initial;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-indicator .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
  border: none;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-indicator .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffa927;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0.2em;
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-indicator--active .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  visibility: visible;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list h4, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list ul {
  margin-left: 0.75em !important;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-bar .mdc-tab {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
}
/* Close Active Tab - Default Tab Over Active Tab */
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab--active:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-bar:has(.mdc-tab--active:nth-child(3)) .mdc-tab:first-of-type {
  left: 195px;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-bar:has(.mdc-tab--active:nth-child(4)) .mdc-tab:first-of-type {
  left: 295px;
  min-width: 160px;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-bar:has(.mdc-tab--active:nth-child(5)) .mdc-tab:first-of-type {
  left: 455px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.nav-tabgroup-container .mdc-tab-bar:has(.mdc-tab--active:nth-child(6)) .mdc-tab:first-of-type {
  left: 605px;
  min-width: 115px;
}
/* Main Nav Mobile */
.nav-drawer-container >:not(.nav-tabgroup-container) a.flhc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.15em;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 1em;
}
.nav-drawer-container button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #006699 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em !important;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  margin-left: 0.75em;
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}
.nav-drawer-container button:hover {
  background-color: #ecf1f7 !important;
}
.nav-drawer-container button:focus, .nav-drawer-container button:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}
.nav-btn-hide, .nav-btn-open {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23006699' stroke='%23006699' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='.8' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 1.35rem;
}
.nav-btn-open {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23006699' stroke='%23006699' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='.6' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
  padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
}
.nav-drawer-container .mdc-drawer-app-content:has(button.mdc-button) > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 1.75em;
}
.nav-drawer-container:has(.nav-btn-hide) button {
  background-color: #ecf1f7 !important;
  z-index: 100;
}
.mat-drawer.mdc-drawer--open:not(.mdc-drawer--closing)+.mdc-drawer-app-content, .mdc-drawer.mdc-drawer--open:not(.mdc-drawer--closing)+.mdc-drawer-app-content {
  margin: initial !important;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list {
  background-color: #006699;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside.mat-drawer, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-description, .nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list .nav-description, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list {
  padding: 0.7em;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-description, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list .nav-description {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-drawer-container .nav-description {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.nav-drawer-container .nav-description small {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1.3em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list ul li, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list ul li {
  margin: 0.7em 0;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list h4, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list h4 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff6;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list ul, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list ul {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list ul li a, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
.nav-drawer-container > aside .nav-list ul li a:hover, .nav-tabgroup-container .nav-list ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
/* Main Nav Mobile Accordion */
.mat-accordion:has(.nav-list) {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin-top: 3.5em;
}
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:has(.nav-list) {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: none;
}
.mat-expansion-panel__content:has(.nav-list) {
  background-color: #005580;
}
.mat-accordion:has(.nav-list) .mat-expansion-panel__summary .after {
  font-size: 1.85em !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.02em #006699;
}
/* Default Accordion Overrides */
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel.mat-expansion-panel--expanded {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel__summary {
  height: 60px !important;
}
.mat-expansion-panel__header {
  flex-basis: 50% !important;
  font-size: 1em !important;
}
/* Hero */
#hero {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #00a0af !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 0;
  margin: 50px 0 200px 0;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#hero:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #008ca0;
  background: rgb(0,140,160);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,140,160,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 60%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 90%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,140,160,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 60%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 90%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,140,160,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 60%, rgba(0,140,160,1) 90%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#00b4cc",endColorstr="#008ca0",GradientType=1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
#hero h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-variant: lining-nums;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
#hero p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  color: #fff;
}
#hero .btn-get-started {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: lining-nums;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  border: 2px solid #ffa927;
}
#hero .btn-get-started:hover {
  background: #ffa927;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Hero Inner */
#hero.inner {
  min-height: 200px;
}
#hero.inner h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  font-size: 1.85em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 102, 153, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
}
/* Hero Search Bar */
#hero .herosearch {
  width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#hero .herosearch div {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}
#hero .herosearch div h1 {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 102, 153, 0.75);
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#hero .herosearch div p {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 102, 153, 1);
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 60%;
}
#hero .herosearch form {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 8px rgba(0, 102, 153, 0.15);
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#hero .herosearch form input[type=search] {
  width: 100%;
}
/* Breakpoint and Down - Hero Styles */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero p {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  #hero .herosearch div {
    padding: 30px 70px;
  }
  #hero .herosearch div h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
  }
  #hero .herosearch div p {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero .herosearch div h1 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }
  #hero .herosearch div p {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  #hero .herosearch div h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hero .herosearch div p {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #hero .herosearch form.roundsearchbar input[type=submit] {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 8 8' style='enable-background:new 0 0 8 8;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:none;stroke:%23FFFFFF;stroke-width:0.6;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;%7D .st1%7Bfill:none;stroke:%23FFFFFF;stroke-width:0.9;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Ccircle class='st0' cx='3.5' cy='3.5' r='2'/%3E%3Cline class='st1' x1='5.1' y1='5.1' x2='6.5' y2='6.5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.9em;
    padding: 0 2em;
    text-indent: -999em;
    }
}
/* Round Search Bar */
form.roundsearchbar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form.roundsearchbar input[type=search] {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
  text-align: left;
}
form.roundsearchbar input[type=submit] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #ffa927;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
form.roundsearchbar input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: #f68e1e;
}
form.roundsearchbar:has(input.form-control:focus) {
  outline: 5px solid #fff4 !important;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
/* Add some breathing room to mobile search bar */
form.form-inline.roundsearchbar {
  width: 85% !important;
}
/* Switch Placeholder Text */
form.roundsearchbar input[type=search]:focus + .switch-text {
  display: none;
}
.switch-text {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #6c757d;
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}
.switch {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-style: normal;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: changeword 12s ease infinite;
}
.switch:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.switch:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.switch:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.switch:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
@keyframes changeword {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<section class="nav-drawer-container">
        <div class="nav-tabgroup-container">
            <div class="topbar">Top Bar</div>
            <div class="menubar">
                <a class="flhc" href="#" aria-label="home">Menu Bar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

<section id="hero">
    <div class="herosearch">
        <div>
            <h1>Test Title</h1>
            <p>Some information about the tests results.</p>
    
            <form class="roundsearchbar" role="search">
                <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Start typing to search" aria-label="Search">
                <span class="switch-text">
                    <em class="switch">Type a test word</em>
                    <em class="switch">Find a specific test</em>
                    <em class="switch">Search for tests</em>
                    <em class="switch">Find more tests</em>
                </span>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>




Blazor call js method to complete the task that blazor component can't do for us, because blazor is designed for developers who want to use c# to replace js so that we'd better to use blazor built-in method instead of create js methods and call then from c# codes. In the js function you shared, we can see element.addEventListener function, I'm afraid that we should use c# codes to add event listener.

This link is aboutt blazor event handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0   By the way, if you had trouble to realize your requirement, you might describe about what you want to achieve in your blazor app

I have updated this post to more accurately reflect the requirements. Thanks for the links.

I'm sorry but I can't get your points and I'm afraid you could create a new question and containing what you want to achieve along with codes and screenshot or simple pictures and this will make other community members to understand your issue better.

is your js code inside wwwroot folder or you added as js code behind for you component ?

In the Blazorfiddle, I am loading the js from an external source at the bottom of the index page.

Created a new question that is more specific to the add/remove class functionality of my problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79227198/add-remove-class-based-on-scroll-position-in-blazor
